# How to use three-way comparison (spaceship op) to implement operator== between different types?

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

Simple Task: I have these two types

```
struct type_a{
   int member;
};

struct type_b{
   int member;
};
```

I want to use this new C++20 spaceship op that everyone says is so cool to be able to write `type_a{} == type_b{}`. I didn't manage to do that. Even if I write `operator<=>` between them, I only ever can call `type_a{} <=> type_b{}`, but never a simple comparison. That confuses me as with a single class, the three-way comparison also defines all the others.

Alternative formulation? How to make it so that `std::three_way_comparable_with<type_a, type_b>` is true?

Comment: It makes little sense to implement the spaceship operator unless you want to compare the sides for something *other* than equality.

Comment: I was just trying everything I could think of

Comment: To explain why `==` is special, consider things like "I want to sort these strings ignoring case, but still treat them as different if they differ in case"

Comment: Well but is `==` really that special? Do other operators like `a<b` get defined automatically when I have `a<=>b`?

Comment: @Basti [\[over.match.oper\]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#8). They are not exactly defined, it’s just that `<=>` participates in overload resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The premise of the question is wrong. You don't use the three-way comparison operator (`<=>`) to implement `==`: you use `==` to implement `==`:

```cpp
bool operator==(type_a a, type_b b) {
    return a.member == b.member;
}
```

The source of confusion is that there is one exception to this rule: if a type declares a *defaulted* `<=>` then it *also* declares a *defaulted* `==`:

```cpp
struct type_c {
    int member;
    auto operator<=>(type_c const&) const = default;
};
```

That declaration is equivalent to having written:

```cpp
struct type_c {
    int member;
    bool operator==(type_c const&) const = default;
    auto operator<=>(type_c const&) const = default;
};
```

But it's not the `<=>` that gives you `==`: it's still the `==`, and only `==`, that gives you `==`.

Comment: So there's nothing gained for comparison *between* types with this at all? In terms of brevity

Comment: @Basti No, there's still a ton: you only have to write one `operator==` instead of four functions (equality both ways and inequality both ways)

Comment: As I recall == [true] also differs from <=> [0] because for efficiency most == will start by comparing the basic size of the items before walking through all of the elements which can shortcut a lot of cases that are not equal. However <=> must always do a full compare because while unequal size implies inequality in all cases it does not imply greater or lesser in many cases.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend making one type convertible to the other:

```
struct type_a{
   int member;
   friend auto operator<=>(const type_a&, const type_a&) = default;
};

struct type_b{
   int member;
   operator type_a() {
       return {member};
   }
};
```

This was the solution before operator<=> too, but now it's simpler to define the comparisons for the common type.

Comment: While this certainly solves the question I stated, I was really trying to solve a more general problem. In particular I find it odd that I can have `a <=> b` work, but still `std::three_way_comparable_with<A, B>` is false - because that trait uses `a==b` internally.